# Retrieving book details by ISBN through Amazon AWS Product Advertising API using .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, isbn

I wish to retrieve book details (in XML) from Amazon Web Services (AWS) Product Advertising API by sending a (conceptually) simple request containing the ISBN number of the book from a VB.NET program.  I have an Amazon AWS Account with an AWS Access Key and Secret key.

I can get to the stage of accessing AWS, but get the following response :

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
  <Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not
  match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
  the >service documentation for details.</Message></Error>
  <RequestId>556dafef-b59f-4829-8ffe-80668cea9707</RequestId>
  </ItemLookupErrorResponse>
```

The code I am using is as follows (here the real Access key and Secret key have been replaced by dummy strings) :

```
Public Shared Function MakeRequestString(IsbnString As String) As String

    Dim stringToSign, strTimestamp, strSignature, strSignedRequest, strParamValuePairs As String

    stringToSign = "GET" & vbLf   'vbLf is Line feed character Ascii 10

    stringToSign &= "webservices.amazon.com" & vbLf

    stringToSign &= "/onca/xml" & vbLf

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    strParamValuePairs = "AWSAccessKeyId=" & GetAWSAccessKey()

    strParamValuePairs &= "&IdType=ISBN"

    strParamValuePairs &= "&ItemId=" & IsbnString

    strParamValuePairs &= "&Operation=ItemLookup"

    strParamValuePairs &= "&Service=AWSECommerceService"

    strTimestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")

    strParamValuePairs &= "&Timestamp=" & UrlEncode(strTimestamp)

    stringToSign = stringToSign & strParamValuePairs

    '---------------------------------------------------------------
    strSignature = MakeSignature(stringToSign)
   '----------------------------------------------------

    strSignedRequest = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?"

    strSignedRequest &= "AWSAccessKeyId=" & GetAWSAccessKey()

    strSignedRequest &= "&IdType=ISBN"

    strSignedRequest &= "&ItemId=" & IsbnString

    strSignedRequest &= "&Operation=ItemLookup"

    strSignedRequest &= "&Service=AWSECommerceService"

    strSignedRequest &= "&Signature=" & UrlEncode(strSignature)

    strSignedRequest &= "&Timestamp=" & UrlEncode(strTimestamp)

    Return strSignedRequest

End Function


Private Shared Function MakeSignature(ByVal StringToHash As String) As String

    Dim myEncoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

    Dim strSecretAccessKey As String = GetSecretKey()

    Dim Key As Byte() = myEncoder.GetBytes(strSecretAccessKey)

    Dim bytStringToHashAsBytes As Byte() = myEncoder.GetBytes(StringToHash)

    Dim myHMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Key)

    Dim HashCode As Byte() = myHMACSHA256.ComputeHash(bytStringToHashAsBytes)

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(HashCode)

End Function


Private Shared Function GetSecretKey() As String

    Return "AAAAAAA Secret Key AAAAAAA"

End Function


Private Shared Function GetAWSAccessKey() As String

    Return "AAAA Access Key AAAAA"

End Function
```

To assemble the above code I have followed the Amazon AWS Product Advertising API Developer Guide Example Rest Requests (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html)

Note, in these guidelines (Step 9) after generating the signature, the instructions are to URL encode the plus (+) and equal (=) characters in the signature, and then include such a URL encoded signature in the signed request - however in the example they are using in the guidelines they seem to URL encode other characters in the signature such as the forward slash character.  I have experimented with the URL encoding but to no avail.

As regards URL encoding, some of the parameters do not contain any potentially problematic characters, this includes the AWS Access Key.  The Timestamp contains - and : characters, the Secret key seems to always have a forward slash (/) character in it.  The calculated signature will have special characters in it.

I note that if you include a space in the timestamp, then the request does not proceed to the stage of returning an AWS error, but an error that the webpage cannot be found (hence the T between the date and the time in the timestamp).

Comment: A revised version of this question was posted (on 5 Oct 2013) on the Amazon AWS Product Advertising API Forum and was subsequently answered (see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=136717&tstart=0[/link]